# Number of subgroups of a group of orders $p^3$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number. Is there a formula for the number of subgroups of

1. $$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$$
2. $$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: If I may guess, it was not me :-),  because it is not so difficult to find the answer by a dutiful search on the web. Don't take it personally.

Comment: Because MathOF is not a place for exercise (or exercise-level) questions. MathStackExchange is the right site for such questions.

Comment: @YCor, Thanks, yes it is easy ... I tried to remove the question but it doesn't  work.

Comment: Maybe because there's an answer? this is (among others) why answering off-topic questions is discouraged.

Comment: @YCor, Yes because it is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following bachelor thesis:

[On p-groups of low power order](https://people.kth.se/~boij/kandexjobbVT11/Material/pgroups.pdf)

there is a chapter on subgroups, which includes the results you're searching for.

It is an useful work for beginners on p-groups.

Comment: The link doesn't work with me : The requested URL /~boij/kandexjobbVT11/Material/pgroups.pdf. was not found on this server.

Comment: try to google the title

Comment: I fixed the URL

Comment: Please don't answer exercise level questions that are not suitable for the site; it makes it impossible to remove them and hard to migrate.